# OleDbException was unhandled syntax error from clause

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data


Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.dataConnectionString)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter credentials ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) from log in where last name=? and ID=?", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Dim count = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar())


            If (count > 0) Then
                MsgBox("log in succeed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("account not found check credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)


            End If

        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dim count = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) 
error

Comment: BTW, Int64 is a Long in vb.net. CLng should work.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar returns int but in object. You need to change it to int then double.

```
 double count= (double)(int)cmdCheck.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: I don't know of any database where Count will return a double. Also, this is a vb.net question not C#.

Answer (score 0):

In your SELECT statement, after the FROM and before your WHERE clause you have two words 'log in'.  If this is your table name it'll have to be enclosed in brackets for sql-server

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) from [log in] where last name=? and ID=?", connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local to where they are used so you can control when they are closed and disposed. `Using...End` Using blocks will do this for you even if there is an error.

Notice that we declare count outside of the Using bock. It it was declared inside the block it would not be visible after the End Using.

We only show message boxes after the connection is closed and disposed by the End Using. Connections are limited resources and should be opened at the last minute and closed as soon as possible.

I am guessing at one problem. When I see ID, I think of a numeric type. Check your database to see what type it is. If it is an integer then you were passing a string value. Type Mismatch!

In the sql statement you need to surround identifiers with spaces in square brackets [ ]. Syntax Error!

Another problem is your usage of `.AddWithValue`. The second parameter is an Object that is the value. You sort of mixed the .Add(String, OleDbType).Value method with the .AddWithValue method.

I was very glad that you are using Parameters which is certainly best practices.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Enter credentials ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Return
    End If
    Dim count As Long
    Using Connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.dataConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) from [log in] where [last name]=@LName and ID=@ID", Connection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
            Connection.Open()
            count = CLng(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    If count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("log in succeed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        MsgBox("account not found check credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
End Sub
```