# No value given for one or more required parameters executenoquery"

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data


Public Class Form1
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.dataConnectionString)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter credentials ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            Return
        End If
        Dim count As Long
        Using Connection As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.dataConnectionString)
            Connection.Open()

            Dim sqlQuery = "SELECT Lastname from Table1 WHERE Lastname='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and ID=" & CInt(TextBox2.Text)

            Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, Connection)
            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TextBox2.Text

            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
            'MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)
            count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Connection.Close()

        End Using
        If count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("log in succeed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("account not found check credentials", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you do a `SELECT`, then using `ExecuteNonQuery` typically is completely wrong. If you have a `SELECT`, you want to get back data - so you need to use `ExecuteReader` or a `SqlDataAdapter` ......

Comment: Looks like multiple people unable to do the same home work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264652/my-program-got-this-error-message-syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expre

Comment: Try use `EXECUTESCALAR` for performing the query if its just checking to see if there is a specific record in the data. Also try use Stored procedures. Makes life a lot easier in terms of using variables and all.

Comment: This is already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253692/oledbexception-was-unhandled-syntax-error-from-clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OleDbException was unhandled syntax error from clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253692/oledbexception-was-unhandled-syntax-error-from-clause)