# my program got this error message.Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID]='

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ADMIN([CusID],[Name]) " &
             "VALUES('" & Me.txtID.Text & "','" & Me.txtname.Text & "' )"

```
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Add Data Successful", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Message")

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Admin " & _
                " SET" & _
                ",[Name]='" & Me.txtname.Text & "'" & _
                " WHERE [ID]=" & Me.txtID.Tag
        MsgBox("Update Data Successful", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Message")
```

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID]='.

Comment: do not EVER do this `[Name]='" & Me.txtname.Text & "'"` read about sql injection. I think that if you eliminate sql injection from your code your problem will solve it self.

Comment: Looks like multiple people unable to do the same home work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263990/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters-executenoquery

Comment: @Rafal which code is most suitable on this code [Name]='" & Me.txtname.Text & "'"

Answer (score 0):

Because Tour Me.TextBox1.Tag is empty.